# getting a mock to run before a pytest fixture is executed

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to conditionally mock something in a function-scoped fixture differently for different tests, so I don't have to create two entirely separate fixtures with nearly-identical code.

```
MY_GLOB_VAR = False

def mocked_build_data():
    with conditional(MY_GLOB_VAR, mock.patch(stuff)):
        build_data()

class Tests:
    @pytest.fixture(scope='function')
    def my_fixture(self, conftest_fixtures):
        inject_test_specific_data_into_db(conftest_fixtures)
        mocked_build_data()
        yield
        cleanup_mysql()

    def test_1(self, my_fixture):
        assert True

    @mock.patch(f'{__name__}.MY_GLOB_VAR', True)
    def test_2(self, my_fixture):
         assert True
```

I need the mock on `test_2` to be applied *before* `my_fixture` is executed, but it's only being applied once I'm in the function body.

Can I either force this the way I'm doing it, or conditionally mock the fixture some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also move patching in a separate fixture and make sure it is requested before `my_fixture` in `test_2`. Fixtures are executed in the order they are listed in test function arguments, so in the signature `def test(fix1, fix2):` the fixture `fix1` will be executed before `fix2` etc. Specifically for your example:

```
MY_GLOB_VAR = False

class Tests:
    @pytest.fixture
    def patch_my_glob_var(self):
        with mock.patch(f'{__name__}.MY_GLOB_VAR', True):
            yield

    @pytest.fixture(scope='function')
    def my_fixture(self):
        print('MY_GLOB_VAR is', MY_GLOB_VAR)
        yield

    def test_1(self, my_fixture):
        assert MY_GLOB_VAR is False

    def test_2(self, patch_my_glob_var, my_fixture):
        assert MY_GLOB_VAR is True
```

Running it with the `-s` flag should yield

```
some_test_module::Tests::test_1 MY_GLOB_VAR is False
PASSED
some_test_module::Tests::test_2 MY_GLOB_VAR is True
PASSED
```

Another option would be requesting the fixture via the `usefixtures` marker, since its returned result isn't explicitly used in the test. This will lead to the same result though, as `patch_my_glob_var` will still be evaluated before `my_fixture`:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('patch_my_glob_var')
def test_2(self, my_fixture):
    ...
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!

Comment: Great answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [indirect parametrization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/parametrize.html#indirect-parametrization) feature of Pytest for that.

> Using the `indirect=True` parameter when parametrizing a test allows to parametrize a test with a fixture receiving the values before passing them to a test.

In your case you could mock the object in the fixture according to the value it receives (through the `request` param). Here is an example showing the principle.

```py
import pytest

MY_GLOB_VAR = None


@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def my_fixture(request):
    if hasattr(request, "param"):
        # use it without param (default case)
        global MY_GLOB_VAR
        MY_GLOB_VAR = request.param
    yield
    # restore initial status
    MY_GLOB_VAR = None


@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_fixture", [True], indirect=True)
def test_true(my_fixture):
    assert MY_GLOB_VAR == True


@pytest.mark.parametrize("my_fixture", [False], indirect=True)
def test_false(my_fixture):
    assert MY_GLOB_VAR == False


def test_none(my_fixture):
    """Example without parametrization"""
    assert MY_GLOB_VAR is None
```

Run the tests

````sh
pytest test_mock.py
# test_mock.py::test_true[True] PASSED
# test_mock.py::test_false[False] PASSED
# test_mock.py::test_none PASSED                                                                                                                                              ```
````

Comment: Doing it this way would mean I have to parametrize every test that uses `my_fixture`, correct?

Comment: @gmoss no you can also use it without parametrization. I've updated the example to illustrate this case.